# LiPo Battery Charger

Tags: batteries

I'm working on a portable PCB using a 3.7V 500mAh LiPo pouch cell. It's designed to be as low powered as possible (under 150uA). I came across the TP4056 however power consumption is too high for it. Then I saw the MCP73831/2 however I'm a bit confused at it's current draw

[image]

Does this mean under normal circumstances current draw is 0.1uA to 2uA. I'm a bit confused on it's conditions particularly with regards to Vstop.

Comment: In standby mode the TP4056 is specified to draw a maximum of 6uA from the battery. I measured a TP4056 board and it drew less than 1uA when the battery was at 4.2V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table you have highlighted refers to current consumption from the Vdd input. It tells you the various current consumptions depending on the input voltage level, and on the status the charger is operating in.

I believe you are more interested in the leakage current that the device absorbs when no wall adapter is present, that is reported in "Battery Discharge Current" section. The maximum current that the device can absorb, when Vdd is not present, is 2 uA, across all the specified temperature range.

Comment: That makes so much more sense! Thanks so much!